# How to save a ranger model in mlr3 without data?

Tags: r, mlr3, r-ranger

I have created a ranger model using `mlr3` library. I saved this model to my machine using following command. The created file is huge in size. The saved file also has the data along with the model. Is there a way to only save the model without the data?

```
learner_ranger = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "prob", predict_sets = c("train", "test"), importance = "impurity", num.threads = 8)
learner_ranger$train(train_task])
save(learner_ranger, file = "model.rda")
```

When I try to load this saved model it does not load the model correctly.

```
learner_ranger = load("model.rda")
str(learner_ranger)
Error in str(learner_ranger) : object 'learner_ranger' not found
```

To reduce the file size and save only the model, I have tried following but I am getting an error

```
save(learner_ranger$model, file = "model.rda")

The error I am getting is -
Error in save(learner_ranger$model, file = "model.rda") : 
  object ‘learner_randomF$model’ not found
```

Comment: What function did you use to create `learner_ranger`?

Comment: I have updated the question and shared all the details.

Answer (score 1):

After some research found that there are two ways to save and load the model in R:

1. using save(), load(): When we use save(), **we will have to load it using the same name.**
2. using saveRDS(), loadRDS(): saveRDS() does not save the model name and we have the flexibility to load the model in any other name. But saveRDS() can only save one object at a time as it is a lower-level function.

Most people prefer saveRDS() over save() as it serializes the object.

I am still looking for ways to save the model without data.